# configure apache vhost for user red

Tags: apache, configuration, config

I have a problem when I try connect my localhost with another pc,I can't see the data of the localhost on another pc, I need make changes from another pc but dont work, I connect to my localhost with IP, I have this configuration on `apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and this work with my project with angular. My app work with REST.

But can't make changes and I can'T see the data store on the localhost.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName my-app

        DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\frontend_dekma

        <Directory C:\xampp\htdocs\frontend_dekma>
            RewriteEngine on

            # Don't rewrite files or directories
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule ^ - [L]

            # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
            RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are you accessing it with a host header `my-app`? Try adding `ServerAlias *` to your conf.

Comment: no I'm accessing with IP '192.168.0.1' is just local, I try ServerAlias * and dont work.

Comment: What are you getting for errors? What is the real error besides `can't see data`? 404? 500? Empty Response? Timeout? Connection Refused?

Comment: Locally I can see the records that I have in my database, from another pc when I connect through the ip I can't see those records. I assumed it was a configuration error because the application works fine.

Comment: Your above code has nothing to do with a database; what is the response code on your client machine?

Comment: No response or response code, just locally shows 10 register, when I connect from another pc it does not show me anything. That's the most frustrating thing there is no error message.

Comment: `No response or response code` you have a misunderstanding of the HTTP protocol then. Your client will have SOMETHING as far as status, whether its a 200, saying all is good from the server, a 400+ saying you sent a bad request, a 500+ saying there was a server error, or different typed of socket exceptions along the way. You can not give me the details I need to know, so the best I can do here is tell you to check the apache server logs to see if you are getting requests from the client, what the client is requesting, and what the server response is. Good luck.